# How to multiply a pandas DataFrame Column by a single value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame with a column of prices in USD and want to convert them to EUR. Yet, I coded a function which supplies the quotation as a return, now I don't know how to multiply all entries in the DataframeColumn by the quotation.

Comment: `df = df.assign(colname=df["colname"] * factor)`

Comment: `df['usd'] *= coefficent`.

Answer (score 3):

```
df['usd'] = df['usd'] * coefficient
```